# search for a particular string in xml and store it in a variable

Tags: xml, shell, sh

I have certain lines in a file(props.xml) like these

```
<property name="property.first" value="some_value_here"/>
<property name="property.second" value="some_value_here/>
```

property.first and property.second are unique

How do I scrap out the **some_value_here**(we don't know) from that file taking the help of name="property.first" or name="property.second"

I just need help with cutting the line after grepping the intended line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple command line tool like `sed` to do this:

```
sed -n '/name="property.first"/{s/.*value="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p}' props.xml
```

This will search for the `name="property.first"` line and then print out the value of the `value` attribute.

Or you can use a simple regex to match the lines you're interested in, and then use a capturing group to extract the value:

```
 grep -E 'property\.(first|second)' props.xml | \
    sed -E 's/.*value="([^"]+)".*/\1/'
```